# Looping through an array, within an array

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to loop through an array within and array. I'm new to loops and I am struggling reading through the documentation.

$data holds the below.

```
Array
(
    [products] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product1
            [1] => Product2
        )
)
```

I'm wanting to use foreach loop and i have tried.

```
foreach($data as $key){
    echo $key->products
}
```

I want to be able to echo out Product 1 and Product 2 separately.

Comment: Move the reference to products(and it should be an array reference), so try `foreach($data['products'] as $key){`

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($data as $value) {
    foreach($value as $product) {
        var_dump($product);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 2 ways using `foerach`

1. You can break the `products` into Key Value

```
foreach( $products as $key => $values) {
    //echo $key. This will print products 
    foreach( $values as $value ) {
       echo $value; //This will print individual products.
    }
}
```

2. But its Better way to do as following in this case by directly supplying foreach the array that you want to loop

```
foreach( $data['products'] as $product ) {
    echo $product;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want array convert to object shortly  use type object casting

```
$productsObject= (object) $array;

print_r($productsObject->products));
```

If you are array iterator

```
foreach($data['products'] as $key){

  echo $key;

}
```

If you use advanced techniques maybe u can use ArrayObject class

Answer (score 0):

Do it with single `foreach()` along with `products` index.

```
<?php
$data = array
(
    'products' => array
        (
            'Product1',
            'Product2'
        )
);

foreach( $data['products'] as $product ) {
    echo $product.PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/bn2KN